# Java Selenium - Using Wildcards in filename while specifying File Path ( Wildcards in File Path in Java Selenium) to Unzip Files

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, wildcard, unzip, filenotfoundexception

I need to unzip files in a specific folder but i don't want to mention file name in file path as it changes every time and it wouldn't be constant. I used wildcard in for filename in file path and it is throwing error File not found Exception

I tried using wildcards in filename of file path to find the file and unzip the same but i'm getting File not found Exception

Please help me on how to use wildcards in filename of file path which is taken as string.

Here goes my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class UnzipFiles {
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        String zipFilePath = "C:\\SAST\\Downloaded XML Files\\detailedreport_*.zip";
        String zipFilePath2 = "C:\\SAST\\Downloaded XML Files\\detailedreport_*.zip";
        
        
  
        String destDir = "C:\\SAST\\Downloaded XML Files\\Unzipped Files";
        String destDir2 = "C:\\SAST\\Downloaded XML Files\\Unzipped Files";
  
        unzip(zipFilePath,destDir);
        unzip2(zipFilePath2,destDir2); 
       
    }

    private static void unzip(String zipFilePath,String destDir) {
        File dir = new File(destDir);
        // create output directory if it doesn't exist
        if(!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
        FileInputStream fis;
        //buffer for read and write data to file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
            ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
          
            while(ze != null){
                String fileName = ze.getName();
                File newFile = new File(destDir + File.separator + fileName);
                System.out.println("Unzipping to "+newFile.getAbsolutePath());
                //create directories for sub directories in zip
                new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                fos.close();
                //close this ZipEntry
                zis.closeEntry();
                ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            }
            //close last ZipEntry
            zis.closeEntry();
            zis.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    private static void unzip2(String zipFilePath2,String destDir2) {
        File dir2 = new File(destDir2);
        // create output directory if it doesn't exist
        if(!dir2.exists()) dir2.mkdirs();
        FileInputStream fis2;
        //buffer for read and write data to file
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
        try {
            fis2 = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath2);
            ZipInputStream zis2 = new ZipInputStream(fis2);
            ZipEntry ze2 = zis2.getNextEntry();
          
            while(ze2 != null){
                String fileName2 = ze2.getName();
                File newFile2 = new File(destDir2 + File.separator + fileName2);
                System.out.println("Unzipping to "+newFile2.getAbsolutePath());
                //create directories for sub directories in zip
                new File(newFile2.getParent()).mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(newFile2);
                int len2;
                while ((len2 = zis2.read(buffer2)) > 0) {
                fos2.write(buffer2, 0, len2);
                }
                fos2.close();
                //close this ZipEntry
                zis2.closeEntry();
                ze2 = zis2.getNextEntry();
            }
            //close last ZipEntry
            zis2.closeEntry();
            zis2.close();
            fis2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\SAST\Downloaded XML Files\detailedreport_*.zip (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: What does this have to do with Selenium? That said, usually your shell will expand the wildcards, but when you open files, there is no shell involved. So you cannot use wildcards. You need to do this manually by getting all files in the directory and filtering which ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just use path with wildcard when refer to a file because wildcard means there might be several files which meet the pattern.

So your choice might be using file filtration like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File rootFolder = new File("/tmp");
    File[] filesToUnzip = rootFolder.listFiles(file ->
            file.getName().matches("detailedreport_.*\\.zip")
    );
    if(filesToUnzip != null){
        for(File file: filesToUnzip){
            // You would do your unzip here
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```